# Limitar tamanho de um array

Tags: php

Possuo um array e irei utiliza-lo de duas formas, em uma usarei todos os elementos desse array, e na outra irei limitar a , por exemplo, 2 elementos, ex:

```
$array = ('nome'=>'Ribossomo', 'snome'=> 'Silva', 'idade'=> 500);
```

usando todos os elementos:

```
$user = $array;
```

agora, como posso pegar só os 2 primeiros elementos desse array? por exemplo, os elementos `nome` e `snome`

```
$teste = ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Creio que se entendi é bem fácil, é só voce pegar o array e colocar a posiçao (índice) que voce quer. Exemplo:

```
<?php
 $primeiro=$array[0]; //Ribossomo
$segundo=$array[1];//Silva

?>
```

Pelo seu comentário, voce poderia fazer assim:

```
<?php
 $limite=2;
for($i=0;$i<$limite-1;$i++){
$novoArray[]=$array[$i];
}?>
```

Essa é a forma que pensei e tenho no momento, pode haver outras, mas essa é a unica que pensei e creio que eu nao precise testar. Esse novo array, vai ser o novo array, com a quantidade de itens que voce definir no $limite.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Na verdade, as duas variáveis retornariam um array, só que a segunda seria um array "cortado" com a quantidade de elementos que eu quero para ser o limite.

Comment: editei ali, dá uma olhada se é isso

Comment: Eu tive essa mesma ideia, mas eu pensei que deveria existir alguma função que já faria isso, e achei uma chamada array_slice, que corta o array e retorna os elementos que você quer, ela serviu pra mim, mas agradeço por sua resposta, obrigado :)

Comment: De nada, eu imaginava que tivesse, mas eu nao tinha como testar aqui entao... Mas que bom que achou

Answer (score 1):

## Simples

```
$teste['nome'] = $array['nome'];
$teste['snome'] = $array['snome'];
```

## Usando a função `array_slice()`

```
$array = array('nome' => 'foo', 'snome' => 'bar', 'test' => 'ok');
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, 2, true));
```

Demonstração: http://ideone.com/pndVWp